# Is there a (scalable) way to live stream audio and video captured using getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webrtc, getusermedia

I know there is WebRTC for peer to peer streaming, but It wouldn't scale well when lots of users join the same room.
So is it possible to capture user media and send it the server that broadcasts it to other participants in the room ?
( or any other method for streaming that works using only HTML5 and JS ).

(A nodejs solution is needed, but a general one will work as well)

Comment: What is your worry with the scaling? Too many ports? Too many copies of the local stream? Too many streams decoding?

Comment: Too many local streams taking too much bandwidth, and too many ports leading to high CPU usage and freezing or blurring of video.

Comment: You can reuse your same localstream(no need for numerous stream encoding) for numerous connections. You will ALWAYS have high CPU utilization because video/audio decoding does not occur until the stream hits the browser. At least, this is the case in WebRTC. You COULD send RAW frames and audio buffers(outside of  a RTCPeerConnection) but that is unsecure, unreliable, and not recommended(you would still have to deal with NAT traversal).